# Avoiding password prompts for git when no ssh public/private keys set for remote repository

Tags: git, ssh

Customer gave me access to some of their git repositories. However, along with the account name I was given a ssh password which seems to imply the rather unconventional expectation to not have public/private key authentication option available. It is taxing to have to dig out and copy-paste the password to the prompt whenever I access the remote git server. Is there a way to store the password in the configuration so I do not need to do this?

The help for `git clone` lists different URL formats for ssh, but does not specify how to add password to this. I added a remote with the URL format of `ssh:${username}:${password}@${hostname}` but it interpreted `${username}:${password}` as the username.

Comment: For now the only option I can think of is to have a wrapper script (expect/pyexpect) that provides the password for me.

Comment: If you have an ssh access with a password — could you upload your own public key using `ssh-copy-id` or even `scp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to educate the customer about ssh key-based
authentication.

That said, if you have to use a password:

Rather than writing an `expect` script, you can use `sshpass` to automatically enter the ssh password. There are a number of ways to provide the password to `sshpass`; for example, you can set the `SSHPASS` environment variable, in which case your command line would look like:

```
sshpass -e git clone ...
sshpass -e git push ...
```

Etc.

You write a wrapper script to avoid having to type out the `sshpass` command line every time. For example, put the following in `sgit` somewhere in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec sshpass -e git "$@"
```

Now, assuming that you have set `SSHPASS`, you can run:

```
sgit clone ...
sgit push ...
```

If you didn't want to store the password in an environment variable, you could instead store it in your local keyring (assuming you're using Gnome) using `secret-tool`. In this case, the wrapper script might look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec sshpass -d4 git "$@" 4< <(secret-tool lookup git customer)
```

This assumes you've previously stored the password using `secret-tool store --label "Some descriptive label" git customer`.

Comment: I am on Mac, using Homebrew to spice things up. Running `brew search sshpass` suggests `sshfs` and tells the following: `We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to ruin SSH's security.` Points to Homebrew, I guess... 

Comment: With Mac+Homebrew the `sshpass` can be easily built from source (search for a `sshpass` repository in github). I created an alias that I source for the terminal session which I use for interacting with the remote repository, and this setup works well for the current development setting. I 100% agree that I could try to educate the customer, but I have a bit of language and culture barrier and time pressure to deliver.